# Multiple parameters references with FindInMap in cloudformation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I've a below Parameters and mappings mentioned in the cloudformation template

```
Parameters:
  ProjectName:
    Type: String

  Environment:
    Type: String

Mappings
  S3Buckets:
    ProjectNameEnvironment1:
      bucketlist: "bucket1,bucket2,bucket3"
    ProjectNameEnvironment2:
      bucketlist: "bucket4,bucket5,bucket6"
```

I want to reference those multiple parameters the list of the mappings in the template. Those two parameters are already being passed during the cloudformation deploy command and I want to use both parameters in the map

I tried with this but not working

```
Resource: !Split [",", !FindInMap [ S3Buckets, !Join [ "", [ !Ref ProjectName, !Ref Environment ] ] , bucketlist] ]
```

While deploying cloudformation template vi CLI getting this error

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template error: every Fn::FindInMap object requires three parameters, the map name, map key and the attribute for return value
```

Can someone help me out

Thank you.

Comment: "but not working" is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: its updated now @Marcin